# Regex to retrieve double numbers from a file but ignoring those with multiple dots

Tags: java, regex

Retrieve all the double numbers in a file and return sum but avoid values with multiple dots.

Test case :

In file

12.3,123.45,19,2.16.8.1.1

output

Expected output -> 154.75
My Output -> 166.01

`-?\\d+\\.?\\d*`    this will retrieve all double numbers but fails in ignoring numbers with multiple dots.

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line;

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+\\.?\\d*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String x = matcher.group(0);
        y = Double.parseDouble(x);
        sum = sum + y;
    }
}
```

Expected output -> 154.75 My Output -> 166.01

Comment: Use `"-?(?<!\\d|\\d\\.)\\d*\\.?\\d+(?!\\.?\\d)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
-?(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)\d*\.?\d+(?!\.?\d)
```

If there is no need to match an optional `-` in front, just remove it.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5A484N/3)

**Details**

- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `(?<!\d)(?<!\d\.)` - immediately to the left, there should be no digit or digit + `.`
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - an optional dot
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?!\.?\d)` - immediately to the right, there must be no digit or `.` + digit.

In Java, use:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?(?<!\\d)(?<!\\d\\.)\\d*\\.?\\d+(?!\\.?\\d)");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that a *substring* of the faulty numbers are actually valid. "1.2.3" should be ignored, but if you just blindly look for valid numbers, then this one could contain either "1.2" or "2.3" as valid numbers.

There's two ways to avoid this:

1. split the line by the known separator "," and varify for each part if it's valid or not *or*
2. Search for *both valid and invalid* numbers and discard the ones that are invalid.

   For this you could use a regex like `-?\d+\.?\d*(\.d*)?` and discard the result when the matching group is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I can't read these regex expressions, they are far too complex for the common man.

Why use complicated regex expressions, that other devs, would have trouble reading. If I had to debug that code I would hate it.

I feel something like below would be lot more readable, and also would reduce the chances of errors, and ease to debug:

```
public double sumFile(String filename) {
    try (Stream<String> linesStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
        return linesStream.mapToDouble(this::sumLine).sum();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

private double sumLine(String line) {
    return Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
            .filter(e -> e.split("\\.").length <= 2)
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
            .sum();
}
```