# replace exact number from a string with ignoring . (dot) in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

example_string ::: "Value >= 1.0, 0 , 2.0" 
I want to replace '0' from a string with '0.0'. But when I tried the below code it returns "Value >= 1.0.0, 0.0 , 2.0"

How to replace the exact 0 with 0.0. simply , how to ignore the value which has dot at its before index ??

```
expression = "Value >= 1.0, 0 , 2.0" 
val = '0' 
converted_val = 0.0 
expression = re.sub(r'\b({})\b'.format(val), str(converted_value), expression, flags = re.I)

>>>>returns "Value >= 1.0.0, 0.0 , 2.0"
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601639/3832970

Comment: A pattern from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58186096/3832970) is more generic, but it will help you to match your `0` even if you cannot use whitespace boundaries.